# Grep search returning a different line

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is my grep search

```
 grep 'Invoker_Slark*' true_pairscore.txt
```

But it returns the line `Invoker_Slardar`. Even though the file contains `Invoker_Slark`. Why is that?

Comment: Are you looking for lines which begin with `Invoker_Slark` or for all which contain it?

Comment: @HaukeLaging : Yes, I was looking for lines that begin with Invoker_Slark. So that means even Invoker_Slarkaslkjfd is a valid result. But not Invoker_Slardar.

Comment: My point is: The code in my answer would match a line `foo_Invoker_Slarkaslkjfd`, too. Is that intended or would that be an invalid result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that `Invoker_Slark*` is considered a regular expression where `k*` means: "zero or more occurrences of k"

That's different from shell globbing patterns where `*` means 0 or more characters.

To search for `Invoker_Slark` anywhere in the line, you need:

1. `grep 'Invoker_Slark' true_pairscore.txt` or
2. `grep -x '.*Invoker_Slark.*' true_pairscore.txt`

If the search string must be at the beginning of the line then this has to be changed to:

1. `grep '^Invoker_Slark' true_pairscore.txt` or
2. `grep -x 'Invoker_Slark.*' true_pairscore.txt`

Comment: I thought that the * is like a substitution for "any number of characters that follow". Which search can fetch me these 2 results? "Invoker_Slarkasdfd" and "Invoker_Slarkoeirute"

Comment: @Ashwin: That is for glob patterns, not regular expressions. Glob is used for shell patterns (expanding to filenames), and a few other places. Regular expressions are used in `grep` (the 're' in 'grep' stands for 'regular expression'), `sed`, and a lot of other places using search patterns. See, for example http://enwp.org/Glob_pattern and http://enwp.org/Regular_expression respectively.

Comment: Putting `.*` at the very end of a `grep` pattern does nothing except possibly slowing down the matching. It would not match any lines that did not match without the `.*` at the end.

Comment: (cont.) With a pattern of `^INITIAL`, the match can be concluded after matching the first 7 chars of each line. With `^INITIAL.*`, after matching the 7 first characters `grep` has to traverse the rest of the line before the whole pattern match can be concluded (`*` is ’greedy,’ matching the longest possible run of characters). This MAY be optimized away when `.*` appears at the end of the pattern...

Comment: @JohanE That is correct but the sense of this being part of my answer is not to recommend this way but to show the analogy for shell pattern matchings `*` in a regex. I admit: There is a difference. The shell needs it because of its implicit `$` (`text$` vs. `text.*$`). But this info should be useful for other cases.